# Broken release upgrade 20.04 to 22.04 has not resolveable unintended upgrades

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04, unattended-upgrades

some days ago I did do-release-upgrade on a rock pi running a little nextcloud server for me. I started the upgrade while I was logged in at the hardware itself, not over network.
While the upgrade was fetching and unzipping the packages, the monitor went black and there was no way to open the screen again. I was still able to get via ssh into the server and found out, that the console was waiting for the user to enter "OK". As you will now, there was no way to do so.

So I killed the upgrade process and started again. I had to fix some problems (don't ask me what it was) and started the upgrade again. It worked and after a while it seems, that it's on 22.04 now. lsb_release tells so.

But since then there is a list of 53 updates, that will not be installed. Here they are:

Die folgenden Pakete sind zurückgehalten worden:
bogofilter bogofilter-bdb bogofilter-common fwupd gcc-10-base guile-2.2-libs inkscape libfwupd2 libfwupdplugin5 libgslcblas0 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5designer5
libqt5designercomponents5 libqt5gui5 libqt5help5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5opengl5-dev libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5quickparticles5 libqt5quickshapes5
libqt5quicktest5 libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5svg5 libqt5test5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5 mariadb-server python-six python3-chardet
qdoc-qt5 qhelpgenerator-qt5 qt5-assistant qt5-gtk-platformtheme qt5-qmake qt5-qmake-bin qt5-qmltooling-plugins qtattributionsscanner-qt5 qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-tools qtdeclarative5-dev
qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qttools5-dev-tools
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 53 nicht aktualisiert.

/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log tells on all packages something like that:
2022-11-11 06:36:18,009 INFO Paket qttools5-dev-tools wird zurückgehalten, weil ein verwandtes Paket zurückgehalten wird oder aufgrund lokaler apt_preferences(5).

At the beginning the log says:
2022-11-11 06:33:35,048 INFO Erlaubte Ursprünge sind: o=Ubuntu,a=jammy, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=jammy-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=jammy-infra-se
curity

Problem is, that nextcloud wont run. Within its log it shows problems in connecting the database (mariadb) and because mariadb-server is unattended, I guess that this is the problem.

Hot do I have to fix this?

Regards

Frank

Comment: Find out which package is held (`apt-mark showhold`), then possibly cancel the hold (`sudo apt-mark unhold [packagename]`).

Comment: sudo apt-mark showhold gives no output. So it seems that there is none. In sources.list all entries are from the URI http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/

Comment: If there is nothing held, try `sudo apt install -f` or `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Once these commands stop doing anything, your installation is clean.

Comment: Neither force install via -f switch nor configure all of dpkg is doing anything.